# Remover solo un valor que se repite en una lista PYTHON

Tags: python

Tengo un ejercicio donde tengo que crear una función en python que me devuelva la misma lista que ingreso, pero si aparece el numero 79, tengo que sacarlo.
Realice la función, pero solo me saca el primer 79 que aparece. Si hay varios 79 en la lista, solo me quita el primero.
Alguna idea de como hacer para que me saque todos los 79 que pueda llegar a tener la lista?
Gracias!

Incluyo codigo que realice:

```
def out_79(lista):
    for i in lista:
        if i==79:
            lista.remove(i)
            return lista
```

Ejemplo:

```
lista=[1,2,4,79,80,1,79,100,79]
print(out_79(lista))
```

El resultado es:

```
[1, 2, 4, 80, 1, 79, 100, 79]
```

Me quita sólo el primer 79

Comment: Incluye en la pregunta el código que tienes de momento, para que te podamos ayudar con base en lo que ya has hecho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema está en dónde pusiste el `return`.

Tu código está "casi bien", pero el error radica en esta parte.

Tratare de explicar todo dentro del código.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def out_79(lista):
    for i in lista:
        if i==79:
            lista.remove(i)
            return lista
''' ^          |            
    |          |            
    |    Aqui esta el error. Esto tiene que 
    |    estar aca.
    |            |
    |____________|

    El error es porque en la primera ocurrencia
    del numero 79 (que te sugiero mejor este dentro de una
    variable), sales de la funcion (con return) regresando
    la lista solo sin la primera ocurrencia del numero.

    La solucion solo es cambiar de lugar el return para que
    no salga en la primera ocurrencia, sino despues de que, con
    el uso del for, se eliminen todas las ocurrencias.

        Esta seria la funcion corregida
          |  con esa observacion.
          |
          |
          v
'''
def out_79_corregido(lista):
    for i in lista:
            if i==79:
                lista.remove(i)
    return lista

lista=[1,2,4,79,80,1,79,100,79]

print(out_79(lista))
print(out_79_corregido(lista))
```

Cuya salida es:

```
[1, 2, 4, 80, 1, 79, 100, 79]
[1, 2, 4, 80, 1, 100]
```

Comment: Genial muchas gracias!!!

Comment: @MajitoPy92 ¡Muy bien! Si te funcionó mi respuesta, no olvides marcarla como la correcta (no sólo puntuarla positivamente) para que personas con la misma duda puedan encontrarla con mayor facilidad.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto..

Con un `for` recorre la lista y compara si es igual a `79`.. en caso de ser cierto le aplicas el `remove()` a la posición..

El código sería así:

```
def lista79(lista):

    print('Lista Original  >> ', lista)

    for i in lista:
        if i == 79:
            lista.remove(79)

    print('Lista Nueva >>> ', lista)


lista = [23,34,22,4,55,79,23,45,79,60]

lista79(lista)
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu respuesta. Mi problema es que si lo uso asi pero dentro de una función no me funciona! (lo inclui en mi pregunta).

Comment: @MajitoPy92 acabo de incluir mi código en una función y funciona sin problemas (no le hice alteraciones, solo de incluirlo en la función)... Por favor revísalo bien y espero te pueda servir. Lo acabo de editar en mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando la función [remove()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html) de las listas

```py
def out_79(lista):
    val = 79
    if val in lista:
        lista.remove(val)
    return lista

lista = [1,2,4,79,80,1,79,100,79]
out_79(lista)
# [1, 2, 4, 80, 1, 79, 100, 79]
```